# Does a ClassLoader load a complete package when there is a wildcard?

Tags: java, package, classloader

How does a Java ClassLoader load imports like `import java.util.*`? I am asking, because I have a custom classloader which sometimes is asked to load a package instead of a class. Example:

```
public Class<?> loadClass(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println(className);
    return parent.loadClass(className);
}
```

Example output:

```
org.test.model.User
org.test.model
org.test.model
```

So it seems like the whole package is requested (may be due to `import org.test.model.*` ?) I am not sure if the imports are causing this (and how to handle it) or if everything is fine and should be this way. Thanks in advance!

Note: This question seems to be the root of my [actual problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25944468/jsp-compilation-error-with-custom-classloader).

**EDIT**
Out of the answer below I do understand that classes are loaded when referenced and the `import` statement is not what is important. Anyhow, why are packages (like "`org.test.model`" in the example above) being loaded? Or what would such a request mean?

Answer (score 0):

'import' is simply syntactic sugar. When your code gets compiled to bytecode, all classes are referenced by their complete package.name

Comment: Does this count for JSP compilation, too?

Comment: And how does this explain the `org.test.model`-request?

Comment: i don't know what you mean by explaining org.test.model

Comment: Sorry, I mean that my logging shows that the class `org.test.model.User` was requested, as well as the "class" `org.test.model`. Do you know why?

Comment: Someone else seems to have jumped in to answer that. Just to reiterate: Classes outside of the JRE are loaded lazily. The JRE is loaded as a unit to prevent package/class hacking

Answer (score 0):

The thing here to understand is that `ClassLoader` don't resolve imports,they resolve classes lazily as they are referenced .They may be resolved eagerly by using `Class.forName(String className)`.

So basically if you are using `import myclasses.unusedPackage.*` ,it doesn't go for resolving all the classes present in the package but will only load a Class as it is referenced.